# Updating TextView with setText() doesn't work in AsyncTask onProgressUpdate()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I'm trying to update my user interface with information about a background task that's going on with an `AsyncTask`. Here's my `onProgressUpdate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... params) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate()");

    StringBuilder currentParam = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder statusMessage = new StringBuilder();

    txtInputFile.setText("Input: " + params[0]);
    txtOutputFile.setText("Output: " + params[1]);
    txtPercentDone.setText("" + MainActivity.getProgressStatus(statusMessage, currentParam) + "%");

    txtStatusMessage.setText(statusMessage);
    txtParamName.setText(currentParam);


}
```

However, none of the TextViews update their text. I am calling `publishProgress()` in my `doInBackground()` method. And the log shows that `onProgressUpdate()` is getting called correctly. I know that the TextViews have been instantiated and are not null. Does anyone know what's going on?

**UPDATE:**
This may have something to do with the fact that this code is in a nested fragment (the ui being updated). When I show this same fragment as the root, everything is working fine. But I need to have it nested in this situation. Why is that making a difference?

Comment: Try to log the thead id's, too.

Comment: @icbytes They show up in LogCat by each of the individual logs and I can confirm that the log shown here is coming from the ui thread.

Comment: And what says debugging? Are you passing params at all?

Comment: @icbytes I am passing params and they are correct, I've logged their values. The method `MainActivity.getProgressStatus` is also correct because I have it hard-coded at the moment.

Comment: Ah i see it. Your stringbuilders are never filled. If status fields are the relevant ones.

Comment: @icbytes The StringBuilders are filled in `MainActivity.getProgressStatus()` I've logged them after the call to that and they are exactly what they should be.

Comment: And you pass values back. Not references. So later on they are empty again.

Comment: No they're not, that was the point of using `StringBuilder` instead of `String`. And even if that's not happening, the `String`s getting passed in to `onProgressUpdate()` are correct and that text isn't getting set either.

Comment: In java all is passed as value, even references. Try an experiment and put params into both other textfields and You will see.

Comment: I've tried even changing them all to a `String` like "Hello" and it still doesn't work. (params in the other ones also doesn't work)

Comment: Oh, you said none of the views gets updated? Sorry for my comments. This is getting to sound strange. Will continue reading. Perhaps you must override the other method to pull the queue from ui thread. Hmmmm.by the way, are the textviews passed or inside main activity? If they are passed to a object which inherits from AsyncTask then you have call by value again.

Comment: Yes none of them are updated. The stranger part is that I update all of them in `onPostExecute()` and it works just fine.

Comment: Perhaps read docs. Im confused too.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your parameters and context from `AsyncTask` and then set them using `runOnUiThread`. If you can't then put your log here to know the issue.

Comment: You don't need `runOnUiThread()`. `onProgressUpdate()` runs on the UI

Comment: Even despite `onProgressUpdate()` running on the ui thread, I've also tried using `runOnUiThread()` and it still doesn't help (like you'd expect it to not change anything).

Comment: Can you post your log to check the issue?

Comment: There's nothing log related happening. There are no exceptions or anything and (found out via debugging) the value of the text in the `TextView` actually changes, it's just not updated on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Every `publishProgress()` are enqueue on the UI thread, so if your `doInBackground` ends before all yours `onProgressUpdate()`, you only see your last ui update.

Try to test adding `Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS)` to check the concurrency of the ui thread.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SOME_VALUE ;i++) {
            publishProgress(""+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```